# Change color of text based on string returned by API

Tags: javascript, html, server-sent-events

In my HTML document I have a  `<div>` with the ID of "text", which I am trying to color based on a value returned by the server.

I have the following JS:

```
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("status.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = event.data;
    };
} else {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support sse";
}
```

So everything works great, but my question is: How can I  change the color of the `<div>` text based on the `event.data` value returned?

For example, if `event.data` returns `online` then I want to change the color of the text to green, and if it returns `offline` then I want to change it to red.

Comment: try .`styel.color=`

Answer (score 0):

Say `event.data` was a json object like this: 
`{ blue: '#00F' }` then, just as you set the innerHTML of the `<div>` to the returned value, we can also update its' style attribute:

After reading your response, I believe I understand what you are trying to do... To start off, and make things easy, we're going to make an object of label-to-color pairs (online: green, offline: red, pause: yellow, etc...):

```
var pairs = {
    offline: '#F00',
    online: '#0F0',
    pause: '#FF0'
}
```

Then we're going to take the value (online, offline, pause, etc...) returned from the server & get the corresponding color from our pairs object. And then set the color of the text to that color.

```
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("status.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        var state = event.data.toLowerCase(),  // ensure offline & not OfFliNe
            color = pairs[state]; // get the corresponding color from pairs object, offline: red

        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = event.data;
        document.getElementById("text").style.color = color;
    };
} else {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support sse";
}
```

All together:

```
var pairs = {
    offline: '#F00',
    online: '#0F0',
    pause: '#FF0'
}

if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("status.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        var state = event.data.toLowerCase(),
            color = pairs[state];

        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = event.data;
        document.getElementById("text").style.color = color;
    };
} else {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support sse";
}
```

Comment: Hi @Darryl - cheers for the answer - I figured this much out myself - however I am trying to alter the colour of "text" depending on the actual word that is returned - ie, Online (green) Offline (red) Pause (Orange) etc! - I tried using if statement but had no joy! Would really appreciate if you could elaborate - thanks

Comment: Sounds good, I had to figure out exactly what you were looking for.  I've updated my answer with what I believe you are looking for, and I have also elaborated the method behind it.

Comment: Didn't work out Darryl - the "text" value just disappears when I use the code above!

Comment: I removed the part where you set the innerHTML. You can just add that back in and the text will be added - I've updated the answer!

Comment: still no joy, I can't for the life of me figure this one out!